# How to add a custom button in daviferreira's medium-editor?

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

I'd like to add a button to create a custom style in a medium-editor button bar (in this case, red text).

I can create the button and make it appear in the button bar:

```
var medium = new MediumEditor(editorBox, {
    buttons: ['bold', ..., 'red'],
    extensions: {
        'red': new MyButton({label: 'R', style: 'color:red'})
    }
});

function MyButton(options) {
    this.options = options;
};

MyButton.prototype.getButton = function(instance) {
    return '<button><span style="' + this.options.style + '">' + this.options.label + '</span></button>';
};
```

I don't know much Javascript. There is documentation at https://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor/wiki/Custom-Buttons-and-Extensions#buttons-defaultbutton-object, but nothing that I recognize as an example, so I don't know how it works in practice.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4):

So you can find an example of something similar to what you're attempting to do at the bottom of that page you linked to: [Examples](https://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor/wiki/Custom-Buttons-and-Extensions#examples)

If you are implementing a basic extension, you'll need to attach an `onclick` handler to the button you're returning in `getButton()`.

So you'd modify your `getButton()` method to do something like this:

```
MyButton.prototype.getButton = function(instance) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = '<span style="' + this.options.style + '"'> + this.options.label + '</span>';
    button.addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this));
    return button;
};
```

You can see an example of this in the [Highlighter Button Example](https://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor/wiki/Custom-Buttons-and-Extensions#highligher-extension-using-checkstate).  In this case, the button is created in the constructor, assigned to `this.button` and an `onclick` handler is attached.

This example uses [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) and the [CSS Class Applier Module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Class-Applier-Module) to apply changes to the current selected text.

For your case, you could do something like this (assuming you use rangy):

```
MyButton.prototype.onClick = function(event) {
    var applier = rangy.createClassApplier("your-red-text-class");
    applier.toggleSelection();
}
```

You could create the class applier as part of the constructor and just reuse it each time the button is clicked.

To make your button in the toolbar be "active" or "inactive" based on the current selection, you can either implement `checkState()` like the Highligher example, or the `isAlreadyApplied()`, `isActive()`, `setActive()` functions explained in the documentation for [Extensions](https://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor/wiki/Custom-Buttons-and-Extensions#methods)